# C Crypto Libraries Supporting HC-128/256?

Tags: c, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I have been searching for a while for a crypto library that I can used on linux to implement HC-128/256 encryption for using on network traffic. Unfortunately, support for this seems rather rare. Bouncy Castle supports it for C# and Java, but I need it for C. I have the source code for the HC-128/256 algorithms, but no examples on how to actually use it.

HC-256 Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HC-256

HC-128 Source Code and Article:
http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/hcp3.html

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a CRYPTOSOCKET class for encrypted comms. It also has a public "encrypt" and "decrypt" function. The socket part really just does encrypt/decrypt and calls send/recv for you. The "socket" functionality of it can be easily stripped out.

This is C++. If you want C, just look at the encrypt and decrypt functions of the CRYPTOSOCKET class and the constructor. Its very simple. Also, this is HC-256, not HC-128.

In a header "crypto.hpp".

```
#include "ecrypt-sync.h"

#ifndef CRYPTO_H
#define CRYPTO_H

class CRYPTOSOCKET{
  public:
/**
* Creates and initializes the structures required for encryption.
* 
* @param[in] socket
* The socket to send and receive data on. This should already be connected.
* @param[in] key
* The key used for encryption and decryption.
* @param[in] iv
* The initialization vector used by AES256 CBC mode. This can just be random bytes.
* 
* @see generateRandom
*/
CRYPTOSOCKET(int socket, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv);

~CRYPTOSOCKET();

/**
* A wrapper for sending data across the connection.
* 
* This encrypts the data into an intermediate buffer 
* prior to sending it across the wire.
*
* @see man send
*/
ssize_t send(const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);

/**
* A wrapper for receiving data across the connection.
* 
* This receives the encrypted data into an intermediate buffer,
* then decrypts it, and writes it to the output buffer.
* 
* @see man recv
*/
ssize_t recv(void *buf, size_t len, int flags);

/**
* Encrypts the specified data and places the encrypted data in the specified buffer.
*
* @param len Used as input for how long the plaintext is, then for output of how long the cipher text is.
* @param[in] plaintext The unencrypted data to encrypt.
* @param[out] ciphertext Where to place the encrypted data.
* 
* @returns A pointer to the ciphertext.
* 
* @see unsigned char *decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, unsigned int len, unsigned char *plaintext)
*/
unsigned char *encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, unsigned int len, unsigned char *ciphertext);

/**
* Decrypts the specified data and places the unencrypted data into the specified buffer.
* 
* @param len Used as input for how long the ciphertext is and as output for how long the plaintext is.
* @param[in] ciphertext The encrypted data to unencrypt.
* @param[out] plaintext The buffer to place the unencrypted data in.
* 
* @returns A pointer to the plaintext.
*
* @see unsigned char *encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, unsigned int len, unsigned char *ciphertext)
*/
unsigned char *decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, unsigned int len, unsigned char *plaintext);

int sock; /**< The underlying socket that this sends and receives on. */

  private:
ECRYPT_ctx e_ctx; /**< The ctx used for encryption. */
ECRYPT_ctx d_ctx; /**< The ctx used for decryption. */
};

#endif
```

And inside "crypto.cpp":

```
#include "crypto.hpp"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

CRYPTOSOCKET::CRYPTOSOCKET(int socket, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv){
  // Initialize the encryptor.
  ECRYPT_keysetup(&e_ctx, key, 128, 128);
  ECRYPT_ivsetup(&e_ctx, iv);

  // Initialize the decryptor.
  ECRYPT_keysetup(&d_ctx, key, 128, 128);
  ECRYPT_ivsetup(&d_ctx, iv);

  sock = socket;
};

CRYPTOSOCKET::~CRYPTOSOCKET(){
  // Nothing to do.
};

unsigned char *CRYPTOSOCKET::encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, unsigned int len, unsigned char *ciphertext){
  ECRYPT_process_bytes(0, &e_ctx, plaintext, ciphertext, len);
  return ciphertext;
}

unsigned char *CRYPTOSOCKET::decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, unsigned int len, unsigned char *plaintext){
  ECRYPT_process_bytes(1, &d_ctx, ciphertext, plaintext, len);
  return plaintext;
}

ssize_t CRYPTOSOCKET::send(const void *buf, size_t len, int flags){
  unsigned char buffer[len];
  encrypt((unsigned char*)buf, len, buffer);
  return ::send(sock, buffer, len, MSG_WAITALL);
};

ssize_t CRYPTOSOCKET::recv(void *buf, size_t len, int flags){
  unsigned char buffer[len];
  int data = ::recv(sock, buffer, len, MSG_WAITALL);

  if(data > 0)
decrypt(buffer, len, (unsigned char *)buf);

  return data;
};
/*******************************************************************
* ECRYPT crap below here....
*/

/* ecrypt-sync.c */

/* *** Please do not edit below here. *** */

//#include "ecrypt-sync.h"

void ECRYPT_init(void){
};

void ECRYPT_process_bytes(
  int action,                 /* 0 = encrypt; 1 = decrypt; */
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* input, 
  u8* output, 
  u32 msglen)                /* Message length in bytes. */ 
{
  u32 i, j, msglen32, keystreamword;

  msglen32 = msglen >> 2;

  for (i = 0; i < msglen32; i++) { 
  keystreamword = generate(ctx);                 /*generate a 32-bit word*/
  for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      *output = *input ^ keystreamword;       /*encrypt one byte*/
      output += 1; 
      input +=1;
          keystreamword = keystreamword >> 8;
      }
  }  

  keystreamword = generate(ctx);
  for (i = 0; i < (msglen & 3); i++) {
      *output = *input ^ keystreamword;       /*encrypt one byte*/
  output += 1; 
  input +=1;
  keystreamword = keystreamword >> 8;
  }
}

void ECRYPT_ivsetup(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* iv)
{ 
u32 W[2560],i;

/* initialize the iv */
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) ctx->iv[i] = 0;
for (i = 0; (i < ctx->ivsize) & (i < 32); i++) {
        ctx->iv[i >> 2] =  ctx->iv[i >> 2] | iv[i];
        ctx->iv[i >> 2] = ROTL32(ctx->iv[i >> 2],8);
}

/* setup the table P and Q */ 

    for (i = 0; i < 8;  i++) W[i] = ctx->key[i];
    for (i = 8; i < 16; i++) W[i] = ctx->iv[i-8];

    for (i = 16; i < 2560; i++) W[i] = f2(W[i-2]) + W[i-7] + f1(W[i-15]) + W[i-16]+i; 

    for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++)  ctx->P[i] = W[i+512];
    for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++)  ctx->Q[i] = W[i+1536];

    ctx->counter2048 = 0;

  /* run the cipher 4096 steps before generating the output */
    for (i = 0; i < 4096; i++)  generate(ctx);  
}

void ECRYPT_keysetup(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* key, 
  u32 keysize,                /* Key size in bits. */ 
  u32 ivsize)                 /* IV size in bits. */
{ 
  u32 i;  

  ctx->keysize = keysize >> 3;
  ctx->ivsize = ivsize >> 3;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) ctx->key[i] = 0;
  for (i = 0; (i < ctx->keysize) & (i < 32); i++) {
        ctx->key[i >> 2] =  ctx->key[i >> 2] | key[i];
        ctx->key[i >> 2] = ROTL32(ctx->key[i >> 2],8);
  }

} /* initialize the key, save the iv size*/

u32 generate(ECRYPT_ctx* ctx) /*one step of the cipher*/
{
        u32 i,i3, i10, i12, i1023;
        u32 output;

        i   = ctx->counter2048 & 0x3ff;
        i3  = (i - 3) & 0x3ff;
        i10 = (i - 10) & 0x3ff;
        i12 = (i - 12) & 0x3ff;
        i1023 = (i - 1023) & 0x3ff;

        if (ctx->counter2048 < 1024) {
            ctx->P[i] = ctx->P[i] + ctx->P[i10] + (ROTR32(ctx->P[i3],10)^ROTR32(ctx->P[i1023],23))+ctx->Q[(ctx->P[i3]^ctx->P[i1023])&0x3ff];
            output = h1(ctx,ctx->P[i12]) ^ ctx->P[i];
        }
        else {                                   
            ctx->Q[i] = ctx->Q[i] + ctx->Q[i10] + (ROTR32(ctx->Q[i3],10)^ROTR32(ctx->Q[i1023],23))+ctx->P[(ctx->Q[i3]^ctx->Q[i1023])&0x3ff];
            output = h2(ctx, ctx->Q[i12]) ^ ctx->Q[i];
        }
        ctx->counter2048 = (ctx->counter2048+1) & 0x7ff;
        return (output);
}

u32 h2(ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, u32 u) {
    u32 tem;            
    unsigned char a,b,c,d;          
    a = (unsigned char) ((u));      
    b = (unsigned char) ((u) >> 8); 
    c = (unsigned char) ((u) >> 16);    
    d = (unsigned char) ((u) >> 24);    
    tem = ctx->P[a]+ctx->P[256+b]+ctx->P[512+c]+ctx->P[768+d];
    return (tem);
}


u32 h1(ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, u32 u) {
    u32 tem;            
    unsigned char a,b,c,d;          
    a = (unsigned char) ((u));      
    b = (unsigned char) ((u) >> 8); 
    c = (unsigned char) ((u) >> 16);    
    d = (unsigned char) ((u) >> 24);    
    tem = ctx->Q[a]+ctx->Q[256+b]+ctx->Q[512+c]+ctx->Q[768+d];
    return (tem);
}



#ifdef ECRYPT_USES_DEFAULT_ALL_IN_ONE

/*
* Default implementation of all-in-one encryption/decryption of
* (short) packets.
*/

#ifdef ECRYPT_HAS_SINGLE_PACKET_FUNCTION

void ECRYPT_process_packet(
  int action,
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx,
  const u8* iv,
  const u8* input,
  u8* output,
  u32 msglen)
{
  ECRYPT_ivsetup(ctx, iv);

#ifdef ECRYPT_HAS_SINGLE_BYTE_FUNCTION
  ECRYPT_process_bytes(action, ctx, input, output, msglen);
#else
  if (action == 0)
ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes(ctx, input, output, msglen);
  else
ECRYPT_decrypt_bytes(ctx, input, output, msglen);
#endif
}

#else

void ECRYPT_encrypt_packet(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx,
  const u8* iv,
  const u8* plaintext,
  u8* ciphertext,
  u32 msglen)
{
  ECRYPT_ivsetup(ctx, iv);
  ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes(ctx, plaintext, ciphertext, msglen);
}

void ECRYPT_decrypt_packet(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx,
  const u8* iv,
  const u8* ciphertext,
  u8* plaintext,
  u32 msglen)
{
  ECRYPT_ivsetup(ctx, iv);
  ECRYPT_decrypt_bytes(ctx, ciphertext, plaintext, msglen);
}

#endif

#endif
```

And inside "ecrypt-sync.h":

```
/* ecrypt-sync.h */

/* 
* Header file for synchronous stream ciphers without authentication
* mechanism.
* 
* *** Please only edit parts marked with "[edit]". ***
*/

#include "ecrypt-portable.h"

#ifndef ECRYPT_SYNC
#define ECRYPT_SYNC

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Cipher parameters */

/* 
* The name of your cipher.
*/
#define ECRYPT_NAME "ECRYPT Stream Cipher HC-256"    /* [edit] */ 

/*
* Specify which key and IV sizes are supported by your cipher. A user
* should be able to enumerate the supported sizes by running the
* following code:
*
* for (i = 0; ECRYPT_KEYSIZE(i) <= ECRYPT_MAXKEYSIZE; ++i)
*   {
*     keysize = ECRYPT_KEYSIZE(i);
*
*     ...
*   }
*
* All sizes are in bits.
*/

#define ECRYPT_MAXKEYSIZE 256                 /* [edit] */
#define ECRYPT_KEYSIZE(i) (128 + (i)*32)      /* [edit] */

#define ECRYPT_MAXIVSIZE 256                  /* [edit] */
#define ECRYPT_IVSIZE(i) (64 + (i)*64)        /* [edit] */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Data structures */

/* 
* ECRYPT_ctx is the structure containing the representation of the
* internal state of your cipher. 
*/

typedef struct
{
  /* 
  * [edit]
  *
  * Put here all state variable needed during the encryption process.
  */
  u32 P[1024];
  u32 Q[1024];
  u32 counter2048;
  u32 key[8];
  u32 iv[8];
  u32 keysize;   /* key size in bytes */
  u32 ivsize;    /* iv size in bytes  */ 
} ECRYPT_ctx;

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Mandatory functions */

/*
* Key and message independent initialization. This function will be
* called once when the program starts (e.g., to build expanded S-box
* tables).
*/
void ECRYPT_init(void);

/*
* Key setup. It is the user's responsibility to select the values of
* keysize and ivsize from the set of supported values specified
* above.
*/
void ECRYPT_keysetup(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* key, 
  u32 keysize,                /* Key size in bits. */ 
  u32 ivsize);                /* IV size in bits. */ 

/*
* IV setup. After having called ECRYPT_keysetup(), the user is
* allowed to call ECRYPT_ivsetup() different times in order to
* encrypt/decrypt different messages with the same key but different
* IV's.
*/
void ECRYPT_ivsetup(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* iv);

/*
* Encryption/decryption of arbitrary length messages.
*
* For efficiency reasons, the API provides two types of
* encrypt/decrypt functions. The ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes() function
* (declared here) encrypts byte strings of arbitrary length, while
* the ECRYPT_encrypt_blocks() function (defined later) only accepts
* lengths which are multiples of ECRYPT_BLOCKLENGTH.
* 
* The user is allowed to make multiple calls to
* ECRYPT_encrypt_blocks() to incrementally encrypt a long message,
* but he is NOT allowed to make additional encryption calls once he
* has called ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes() (unless he starts a new message
* of course). For example, this sequence of calls is acceptable:
*
* ECRYPT_keysetup();
*
* ECRYPT_ivsetup();
* ECRYPT_encrypt_blocks();
* ECRYPT_encrypt_blocks();
* ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes();
*
* ECRYPT_ivsetup();
* ECRYPT_encrypt_blocks();
* ECRYPT_encrypt_blocks();
*
* ECRYPT_ivsetup();
* ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes();
* 
* The following sequence is not:
*
* ECRYPT_keysetup();
* ECRYPT_ivsetup();
* ECRYPT_encrypt_blocks();
* ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes();
* ECRYPT_encrypt_blocks();
*/

/*
* By default ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes() and ECRYPT_decrypt_bytes() are
* defined as macros which redirect the call to a single function
* ECRYPT_process_bytes(). If you want to provide separate encryption
* and decryption functions, please undef
* ECRYPT_HAS_SINGLE_BYTE_FUNCTION.
*/
#define ECRYPT_HAS_SINGLE_BYTE_FUNCTION  1  /* [edit] */
#ifdef ECRYPT_HAS_SINGLE_BYTE_FUNCTION

#define ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes(ctx, plaintext, ciphertext, msglen)   \
  ECRYPT_process_bytes(0, ctx, plaintext, ciphertext, msglen)

#define ECRYPT_decrypt_bytes(ctx, ciphertext, plaintext, msglen)   \
  ECRYPT_process_bytes(1, ctx, ciphertext, plaintext, msglen)

void ECRYPT_process_bytes(
  int action,                 /* 0 = encrypt; 1 = decrypt; */
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* input, 
  u8* output, 
  u32 msglen);                /* Message length in bytes. */ 

#else

void ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* plaintext, 
  u8* ciphertext, 
  u32 msglen);                /* Message length in bytes. */ 

void ECRYPT_decrypt_bytes(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* ciphertext, 
  u8* plaintext, 
  u32 msglen);                /* Message length in bytes. */ 

#endif

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Optional features */

/* 
* For testing purposes it can sometimes be useful to have a function
* which immediately generates keystream without having to provide it
* with a zero plaintext. If your cipher cannot provide this function
* (e.g., because it is not strictly a synchronous cipher), please
* reset the ECRYPT_GENERATES_KEYSTREAM flag.
*/

#define ECRYPT_GENERATES_KEYSTREAM
#ifdef ECRYPT_GENERATES_KEYSTREAM

void ECRYPT_keystream_bytes(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx,
  u8* keystream,
  u32 length);                /* Length of keystream in bytes. */

#endif

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Optional optimizations */

/* 
* By default, the functions in this section are implemented using
* calls to functions declared above. However, you might want to
* implement them differently for performance reasons.
*/

/*
* All-in-one encryption/decryption of (short) packets.
*
* The default definitions of these functions can be found in
* "ecrypt-sync.c". If you want to implement them differently, please
* undef the ECRYPT_USES_DEFAULT_ALL_IN_ONE flag.
*/
#define ECRYPT_USES_DEFAULT_ALL_IN_ONE        /* [edit] */

/*
* Undef ECRYPT_HAS_SINGLE_PACKET_FUNCTION if you want to provide
* separate packet encryption and decryption functions.
*/
#define ECRYPT_HAS_SINGLE_PACKET_FUNCTION     /* [edit] */
#ifdef ECRYPT_HAS_SINGLE_PACKET_FUNCTION

#define ECRYPT_encrypt_packet(                                        \
ctx, iv, plaintext, ciphertext, mglen)                            \
  ECRYPT_process_packet(0,                                            \
ctx, iv, plaintext, ciphertext, mglen)

#define ECRYPT_decrypt_packet(                                        \
ctx, iv, ciphertext, plaintext, mglen)                            \
  ECRYPT_process_packet(1,                                            \
ctx, iv, ciphertext, plaintext, mglen)

void ECRYPT_process_packet(
  int action,                 /* 0 = encrypt; 1 = decrypt; */
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* iv,
  const u8* input, 
  u8* output, 
  u32 msglen);

#else

void ECRYPT_encrypt_packet(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* iv,
  const u8* plaintext, 
  u8* ciphertext, 
  u32 msglen);

void ECRYPT_decrypt_packet(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* iv,
  const u8* ciphertext, 
  u8* plaintext, 
  u32 msglen);

#endif

/*
* Encryption/decryption of blocks.
* 
* By default, these functions are defined as macros. If you want to
* provide a different implementation, please undef the
* ECRYPT_USES_DEFAULT_BLOCK_MACROS flag and implement the functions
* declared below.
*/

#define ECRYPT_BLOCKLENGTH 4                  /* [edit] */

#define ECRYPT_USES_DEFAULT_BLOCK_MACROS      /* [edit] */
#ifdef ECRYPT_USES_DEFAULT_BLOCK_MACROS

#define ECRYPT_encrypt_blocks(ctx, plaintext, ciphertext, blocks)  \
  ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes(ctx, plaintext, ciphertext,                 \
(blocks) * ECRYPT_BLOCKLENGTH)

#define ECRYPT_decrypt_blocks(ctx, ciphertext, plaintext, blocks)  \
  ECRYPT_decrypt_bytes(ctx, ciphertext, plaintext,                 \
(blocks) * ECRYPT_BLOCKLENGTH)

#ifdef ECRYPT_GENERATES_KEYSTREAM

#define ECRYPT_keystream_blocks(ctx, keystream, blocks)            \
  ECRYPT_keystream_bytes(ctx, keystream,                           \
(blocks) * ECRYPT_BLOCKLENGTH)

#endif

#else

/*
* Undef ECRYPT_HAS_SINGLE_BLOCK_FUNCTION if you want to provide
* separate block encryption and decryption functions.
*/
#define ECRYPT_HAS_SINGLE_BLOCK_FUNCTION      /* [edit] */
#ifdef ECRYPT_HAS_SINGLE_BLOCK_FUNCTION

#define ECRYPT_encrypt_blocks(ctx, plaintext, ciphertext, blocks)     \
  ECRYPT_process_blocks(0, ctx, plaintext, ciphertext, blocks)

#define ECRYPT_decrypt_blocks(ctx, ciphertext, plaintext, blocks)     \
  ECRYPT_process_blocks(1, ctx, ciphertext, plaintext, blocks)

void ECRYPT_process_blocks(
  int action,                 /* 0 = encrypt; 1 = decrypt; */
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* input, 
  u8* output, 
  u32 blocks);                /* Message length in blocks. */

#else

void ECRYPT_encrypt_blocks(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* plaintext, 
  u8* ciphertext, 
  u32 blocks);                /* Message length in blocks. */ 

void ECRYPT_decrypt_blocks(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* ciphertext, 
  u8* plaintext, 
  u32 blocks);                /* Message length in blocks. */ 

#endif

#ifdef ECRYPT_GENERATES_KEYSTREAM

void ECRYPT_keystream_blocks(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx,
  u8* keystream,
  u32 blocks);                /* Keystream length in blocks. */ 

#endif

#endif

/*
* If your cipher can be implemented in different ways, you can use
* the ECRYPT_VARIANT parameter to allow the user to choose between
* them at compile time (e.g., gcc -DECRYPT_VARIANT=3 ...). Please
* only use this possibility if you really think it could make a
* significant difference and keep the number of variants
* (ECRYPT_MAXVARIANT) as small as possible (definitely not more than
* 10). Note also that all variants should have exactly the same
* external interface (i.e., the same ECRYPT_BLOCKLENGTH, etc.). 
*/
#define ECRYPT_MAXVARIANT 1                   /* [edit] */

#ifndef ECRYPT_VARIANT
#define ECRYPT_VARIANT 1
#endif

#if (ECRYPT_VARIANT > ECRYPT_MAXVARIANT)
#error this variant does not exist
#endif

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

#endif


/* ===========================================================================

        Added functions:    HC-256 Mandatory functions 

============================================================================== */

#define f1(x)    (ROTR32((x),7) ^ ROTR32((x),18) ^ ((x) >> 3))
#define f2(x)    (ROTR32((x),17) ^ ROTR32((x),19) ^ ((x) >> 10))

/*




void ECRYPT_keysetup(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* key, 
  u32 keysize,                // Key size in bits. 
  u32 ivsize);                // IV size in bits. 

void ECRYPT_ivsetup(
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* iv);

void ECRYPT_process_bytes(
  int action,                 // 0 = encrypt; 1 = decrypt; 
  ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, 
  const u8* input, 
  u8* output, 
  u32 msglen);                // Message length in bytes. 

*/

void ECRYPT_init(void);
u32 h1(ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, u32 u);
u32 h2(ECRYPT_ctx* ctx, u32 u);
u32 generate(ECRYPT_ctx* ctx);
```

Then use "ecrypt-machine.h", "ecrypt-config.h", and "ecrypt-portable.h" from here: http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/p3ciphers/hc/hc256_p3source.zip

Here is a quick application to test it. You will have to create the "generateRandom" function, or just make up some random bytes lol.

```
#include "crypto.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  CRYPTOSOCKET *socket;
  unsigned char key[32];
  unsigned char iv[32];
  unsigned char buf1[1024];
  unsigned char buf2[1024];
  unsigned char buf3[1024];
  char *teststring = "This is a test.\n";

  // Generate a random key
  generateRandom(key, 32);

  // Generate a random IV
  generateRandom(iv, 32);

  // Create a new cryptosocket with that key and iv.
  socket = new CRYPTOSOCKET(0, key, iv);

  // Copy teststring into buffer 1
  sprintf((char*)buf1,teststring);

  // Encrypt buffer 1 and placed the encrypted contents into buffer 2.
  socket->encrypt(buf1,strlen(teststring), buf2);

  // Decrypt buffer 2 into buffer 3.
  socket->decrypt(buf2, strlen(teststring), buf3);

  // Print out whats in buffer 3.
  printf((char*)buf3);

}
```

Comment: Oh, please keep in mind that this is the linux implementation of this. For win32 you will have to change a couple things, specificaly you will need "winsock2.h" instead of "sys/types.h" and "sys/socket.h"